how to make Webextension content_scripts load on opened pages after the first?
Problem: The  content_scripts specified in the manifest.json of a WebExtension are only applied to the first page loaded in a window created by the extension regardless of how non-specific my matches are.
Details: I'm making an extension for a bookmarking site.
The plugin opens a window with a form at /bookmarks/new. Content scripts are injected at this point. The user then fills in and submits the form.
IF the form successfully submits it redirects to /bookmarks/success  content scripts are NOT injected here even if one of my matches is  "*://*/*"
Questions:

Is it possible for content_scripts to be injected into subsequent page loads using only instructions in the manifest.json?
If not, is there something I can add a listener to in the extension that will tell me about page changes & their url?

I'm currently testing in Firefox, but I'm hoping to make this extension work in it and Chrome.
I've failed to find answers to either of these questions.

Use "matches":["*://*.site.com/*"] and MutationObserver (example).

MutationObservers observe the content of the page and can't observe the location of the page. It's possible the user may pass through a login page before getting to the success page so i can't just check if any random object changed.

Usually when the URL changes something in DOM changes as well. I don't think I've seen an exception, but indeed it's possible, see this answer.

thank you for the pointer, it was the clue i needed but the ultimate solution was non-obvious. I've put together an answer with the details. Please edit / correct if it needs changes / additional info.

@woxxom's comments pointed me in the right direction, but the ultimate solution is convoluted and non-obvious.
Notes:

You need to inject a mutation observer into the page via content_scripts.
Its variables will be thrown out on page loads, so they're useless for comparing old vs new urls
You can't stick the mutation observer in your background scripts for reasons I don't understand. It just doesn't work. [edit this post you can explain]
If the page you need is not the first page then you can't put the test for if its on the correct url in the content script


use a nice generic matcher that'll match all the pages on the relevant site. Especially if the user might get redirected to a login page before getting to the page you were trying to open.
have something that can handle messages in your background script

// contents of your content script
// note that it is NOT comparing urls
new MutationObserver(() => {
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({event: 'page_loaded', url: location.href})
}).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});

Set up a listener for this in your background script
// Set up a listener
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
    // App.handleMessage is specific to my plugin
    // all that matters is that this is an async function
    // that is ready to handle an url
    App.handleMessage(message.event, message.url)
})

then, in the function that actually checks the url that came through have your test to see if this page you've found yourself on is the right one.
    async checkPageLoaded(url) {
        if (url.match(/\/bookmarks\/success\?closeable=true/)) {
            this.doTheThing()
        }
    },

